# Unix awk pass variable as fileName

Tags: file, unix

I am using the following command to split one file into two.

```
currentCouponFile="$DIR/kozo_agency_current_coupon_ts-"$HMD_EFF_DT".csv"
agencySpreadFile="$DIR/kozo_agency_spread_ts-"$HMD_EFF_DT".csv"

awk -F '|' 'BEGIN{OFS=","};{$1=$1; if(NF == 2){print > "$currentCouponFile"}else{ print > "$agencySpreadFile"}}' $fileName
```

Doing echo on `currentCouponFile` and `agencySpreadFile` gives me the desired filename.

However the resultant file get created as `$agencySpreadFile` and `$currentCouponFile`. Not the in .csv format.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use shell variables inside `awk`.

```
currentCouponFile="$DIR/kozo_agency_current_coupon_ts-"$HMD_EFF_DT".csv"
agencySpreadFile="$DIR/kozo_agency_spread_ts-"$HMD_EFF_DT".csv"

    awk -F '|' -v current="$currentCouponFile" -v agency="$agencySpreadFile" '
       BEGIN{OFS=","}
       {
       $1=$1;
       if(NF == 2) 
          {print > current}
       else
          {print > agency}
       }' $fileName
```